# Configure ADFS Relying Party SAML response to include "NameFormat" in Attributes

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

I have an older ADFS system running on Server 2012 R2.  We're trying to configure a IDP initiated relying party trust based on the Service Provider's specifications so that the outgoing SAML response looks like this:

```
    <Attribute Name="Company" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <AttributeValue>ABCD1234</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Group" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <AttributeValue>Basic</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="UserName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <AttributeValue> employee@company.com </AttributeValue>
    </AttributeStatement>
```

However, after configuring a Relying Party Trust and associated Claim Rules in ADFS, our outgoing SAML response is missing the "NameFormat" part and looks like this:

```
    <Attribute Name="Company">
        <AttributeValue>ABCD1234</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Group">
        <AttributeValue>Basic</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="UserName">
        <AttributeValue>employee@company.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

The three Claim Rules that make the response are:

```
 => issue(Type = "Company", Value = "ABCD1234");

 => issue(Type = "Group", Value = "Basic");

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("UserName"), query = ";mail;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

How can I configure things to include the "NameFormat" part in the outgoing attributes?  The SP states that it's mandatory to include them.

Comment: The correct method was : 
=> issue(Type = "Company", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/attributename"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic", Value = "ABCD1234");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with "Properties".

e.g.

c:[Type == "http://mycompany/internal/sessionid"]
=> issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient",
Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/namequalifier"] = http://xxx/adfs/services/trust, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/spnamequalifier"] = "sp_test");

More [here](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2012/10/adfs-nameid-qualifier-in-claims.html) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0f288d7-881c-499a-9d40-75a5b722bd40/how-to-send-a-custom-attribute-name-quotuseremailquot-as-nameformat-type-of?forum=ADFS).

Comment: Thanks for finding that --Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" -- option, it looks promising.  However, I've added it to the first two simple "issue" rules and the parser lets it through but the SAML response is unchanged.  Adding it to the 3rd AD Email lookup rule give a parsing error:  "POLICY0030:Syntax error, unexpected PROPERTY, expecting one of the following:" and then either TYPE, QUERY, or PARAM depending on what spot in the rule that I place it.

Comment: I've tried a number of different methods based around the "Properties" keyword that all get through the parser fine but produce the same results without the "NameFormat" information.  I've gone ahead and contacted MS ADFS support to see what they can turn up.

Comment: MS got back to me with a solution.  It definitely was "Properties" like you thought but ironically enough, it was "AttributeName" that was the right keyword. 
 Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties//attributename"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"

Comment: your blog page "Tips and tricks with ADFS claims rules" (specifically "Searching for one attribute that’s linked to another") also helped me fix a different longstanding item on our SSO users wishlist for a different SP that we use.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice! I used to do a ton of stuff with ADFS but not much these days. I don't have a test instance anymore. Most of my customers have migrated to Azure AD with PTA or else their ADFS just works and they don't do new development.